# How to split BTG in electrum and send to new ledger nano s wallet

Tags: electrum, blockchain-fork, bitcoin-gold

I currently have all my BTC on my electrum wallet, and I had them before the BTG fork. I haven't done anything regarding splitting since the fork, but now that I have the ledger nano s, I want to move my BTC from electrum to the ledger.

Now I am in no way familiar with a) splitting BTC/BTG and b) replay attacks, but I am afraid of losing any coins in the process. As I understand, I shall do the following:

- Make a regular BTC transaction to move all BTC from electrum to the ledger nano s BTC address
- Get a BTG wallet, and import electrum's private keys in it. Then, I have 'claimed' the BTG
- Make a regular BTG transaction and move the BTG from the BTG wallet to the ledger nano s BTG address

Is this correct? Is there any chance of losing anything with this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you stated look good to me. It would be prudent to wait for a few confirmations of your BTC transactions, to make sure your BTC are safe, before exporting your private keys from electrum.

Comment: I actually ended up beeing brave and transferring my BTC from electrum to ledger. According to BTG they have replay protection in place, and BTC transactions are invalid on the BTG chain.

The BTC showed up in the ledger just fine. I haven't bothered with claiming BTG yet though, since I don't really need it at the moment. Also I lack a good BTG wallet (I am on macos (not windows) and I don't have android, and not sure if I should trust the iOS one).